# Python read 100's of text files

Tags: python

I have some data in simplejson format in txt files, which I read using:

```
with open("my_file.txt") as f: any_variable = simplejson.load(f)
```

It works fine, no problems. However, I now have 100's of such text files (some of which, I dont know the names for!) to read from and I was wondering, if there was a pythonic way to read all these files and assign them to say: any_variable1 to any_variableN. I dont really care in what order they are read in.

Obviously, a simple way would be to loop and store results, yet, I was wondering if there was a pythonic way here.

Comment: When you're thinking of having a load of `any_variableN` variables, it almost always means you should use a list (or in some cases a dictionary), and refer to `any_variable[N]`.

Comment: Thomas, please see my comment to the answer below. I have actually tried it to be a array. However, something is not working as shown in my dpaste error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the files are inside a directory, you can use:

```
 variables = [] 
 path = "/your/path"
 for filename in os.listdir(path):
     variables.append(simplejson.load(open(os.path.join(path, filename))))
```

Comment: ,Thomas: Actually, I have tried excatly what you have suggested. However, I get an error when I do this(http://dpaste.com/694374/). But, when I simply use: "with open("my_file.txt") as f: any_variable = simplejson.load(f)" on all the files in the directory, I get no error and everything is fine. Any clues as to why this is? Many thanks again.

Comment: Can you post your full example, as it looks like you open the wrong file path or there is no JSON data in it.

Comment: If you add `print filename` to the for loop, you can see which file it falls down on.

Comment: Here is the code: http://dpaste.com/694380/ I am sure it has JSON data in it, because, when I read individual files in (as an example, I took 3 files only), it seems to work fine.

Comment: Are there any other files inside the directory which are probably not JSON? Pleas euses Thomas' print line to debug the file which is failing.

Comment: Ah. I got whats happened. Unfortunately, I had the .py file of the script in the directory. Very sorry for such a stupid question!